# How is the initial and recurrent `FirebaseRemoteConfig` requests authenticated in an android app to get remote configuration values?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

How is the initial and recurrent `FirebaseRemoteConfig` requests authenticated in an android app to get remote configuration values?

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
firebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {

          }
});
```

**Edit:**

- I would like to access the configuration values through `curl`
- The documented [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest#step_3_get_json_from_with_the_api) uses a bearer token, but the android implementation doesn't have any bearer or authorization key.

  ```
  curl --compressed -D headers -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -X GET https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-id/remoteConfig -o filename
  ```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Is something not working the way you expect?

Comment: I would like to access the configuration values through `curl`